# Php code for create a file

Tags: php, fopen

we need to create a file on localhost from live host server.After entering URL in live server we need to create a file in particular path.i am using godaddy server, please suggest if you have anything to help?

Comment: Do you need to do this with PHP? You can for instance use ssh

Comment: <?php
//$file = 'people.txt';
$newdata="c:\\resource.txt";
$current = "John Smith\n";
$file = fopen($newdata, "w");
fwrite($file, $current);
fclose($file);
$current = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
echo "Created a file";
?>

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to open the file, if it doesn't exist, it will create it

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.yoursite.com/file.txt", "a+");
```

a+ in fopen allows you to write to the file if you need to, use w+ if you want to overwrite any existing content

```
fwrite($handle, $new_file_content);
```

Free up memory when done

```
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
$fileContents = "File contents";
if(false !== file_put_contents("/path/to/file.txt", $fileContents)){
    echo 'write successful';
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a file on your computer? From the webserver? Unfortunately that isn't possible. You could send a download header - to prompt a download in that case, however you won't be able to control the path where it will be stored.

Comment: A web-browser specifically doesn't have access to the filesystem. Hypothetically you could perhaps run an applet or browser plugin to ask for this type of access, but certainly not directly from your php code.